# Как правильно найти и обернуть в теги кавычки?

Tags: javascript, html

Допустим, что есть такая структура (3 вида элементов p).

```
// ...Много похожих элементов
<p>Элемент &lt;<span class="red">script</span>&gt; - очень хороший элемент.</p>
<p>Текст без символов-мнемоников, но имеет <b>элементы</b> внутри</p>
<p>Текст без символов-мнемоников и без узлов-элементов внутри</p>
// ...Много похожих элементов
```

Можно примерно так с помощью JS найти все элементы `<p>`, которые **могут** иметь мнемоники (кавычки, в моём случае).

```
let textElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("p")).filter( item => item.firstElementChild );
```

В общем, мне нужно через JS обернуть каждую кавычку на странице в тег `<b>`. Через textContent это сделать нельзя, так что самый очевидный для меня вариант - **innerHTML**. Проблема в том, что в innerHTML есть теги, а значит и лишние кавычки, при выделении которых всё сломается. И ещё, при добавлении в цикле индексы сдвигаются, что усложняет задачу. Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(p =>
  p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(/&\w+;/g, `<b>$&</b>`)
)
```

```css
b {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Элемент &lt;<span class="red">script</span>&gt; - очень хороший элемент.
Элемент &lt;<span class="red">script</span>&gt; - очень хороший элемент.
Элемент &lt;<span class="red">script</span>&gt; - очень хороший элемент.
Элемент &lt;<span class="red">script</span>&gt; - очень хороший элемент.</p>
<p>Текст без символов-мнемоников, но имеет <b>элементы</b> внутри</p>
<p>Текст без символов-мнемоников и без узлов-элементов</p>
```